# Why does zip use a lot of memory in Python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, out-of-memory

I have a script that takes x, y and z coordinates, creates a grid and interpolates the coordinates. It then looks whether the points are in a certain polygon. When running the script I got a memory error. In order to find a problem with the memory usage I installed `memory_profiler` and found the result shown below:

```
61                                         # define grid.
62  156.887 MiB    0.000 MiB               xi = np.arange(roundDown(XZ[~np.isnan(XZ)].min(),5), roundUp(XZ[~np.isnan(XZ)].max(), 5)+5, 5).astype(np.int32)
63  156.887 MiB    0.000 MiB               yi = np.arange(roundDown(YZ[~np.isnan(YZ)].min(),5), roundUp(YZ[~np.isnan(YZ)].max(), 5)+5, 5).astype(np.int32)
64  325.457 MiB  168.570 MiB               gxi, gyi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
65  493.922 MiB  168.465 MiB               zi = griddata((XZ[~np.isnan(XZ)].ravel(), YZ[~np.isnan(YZ)].ravel()), dep[~np.isnan(dep)].ravel(), (gxi, gyi), method='linear')
66
67                             ##            sel = ~np.isnan(zi.ravel())
68
69                             ##            xList = gxi.ravel()[~np.isnan(zi.ravel())]
70                             ##            yList = gyi.ravel()[~np.isnan(zi.ravel())]
71  563.383 MiB   69.461 MiB               zList = zi.ravel()[~np.isnan(zi.ravel())]
72
73                             ##            points = zip(xList, yList)
74 1239.020 MiB  675.637 MiB               points = zip(gxi.ravel()[~np.isnan(zi.ravel())], gyi.ravel()[~np.isnan(zi.ravel())])
```

I understand that, given that there are many points, `gxi`, `gyi` and `zi` use quite some memory, but why would the `zip()` function also use a lot of memory?

I tried using `itertools.izip()`, but since the points need to go into another function (`matplotlib.path.Path.contains_points`) that seems to require a list of tuples instead of a generator that doesn't work.

Does anybody have any advice to solve the matter?

Comment: Try creating temporary variables for the parameters to zip() so that you can test whether it is zip() that is consuming a lot of memory, or the creation of the arguments to zip().

Comment: I don't know numpy well enough to speak to your calculations, but `zip()` in Python 2 will produce a list.  If you're zipping together some big lists, then the result will allocate a large amount of memory to hold the list.

Answer (score -1):

[Updated 19/09/2019]
As pointed out by John Szakmeister:
- In python2, zip() creates new underlying list, which takes large memory usage. So to reduce memory usage, use itertools.izip(), it will return an appropreate iterator.

[Wrong case - correct only in python3]
As mentioned in [this blog post](https://stackabuse.com/the-python-zip-function/), zip() function does not create underlying list, it just create an iterator object to help you iter through input iterables.

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP is using Python 2 (at least the question is tagged as being Python 2).  In Python 2, [zip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) produces a list, not an iterator.  `itertools.izip()` is how you get an iterator version in Python 2.